# Extract key-value combo from json object

Tags: json, reactjs, object, react-native

I have the following object that gets returned from an API fetch

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: "Leanne Graham",
 zipcode: "92998-3874",
 username: "Bret",
 email: "Sincere@april.biz",
 ..... (only the ones above matter to me) 
}
```

I want to extract only certain parts of the objects ( e.g. zipcode ). I tried the following: `this.props.users.zipcode` `JSON.parse` `JSON.stringify` but all of them return `undefined` when logging to console. Do you mind helping me?

Comment: You'll need to share more of your code in order for anyone to understand your problem. What you've provided just shows some pseudo JSON, but your question includes `this.props.users` - where is `this.props.users` being set?

Comment: I'm using redux and redux saga to make my API fetch but i don't think the problem is on that end, that's why I haven't provided the code for it. And to answer your question, `this.props.users` is being set in `mapStateToProps` in the `Container` of the component that I'm using. using `console.log() `just after i `dispatch` my `action` gives me the data seen above, but i just cant figure what to do next with it

Comment: can you show the data of console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.user)); ?

Comment: `[{"id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz","address":{"street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}},"phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442","website":"hildegard.org","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Crona","catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net","bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}}]`

Comment: I think you need to provide more code

Comment: @Colin just imagine i have the data above and i want to display `<View><Text>I want to show the zipcode here</Text></View>`

Comment: Try this code ==> var data= this.props.user; console.log(data[0].address.zipcode);

Comment: @Vipul Tried this as well, just says "cannot read property 'address' of undefined". Thanks anyway:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering only your data the below possible solution will help you in get the values of the keys.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class Test extends Component {
  render(){
    let data = [{"id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz","address":{"street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}},"phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442","website":"hildegard.org","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Crona","catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net","bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}}]
    data.map((d, i) => {
      console.log("values", d.name, d.email, d.address.zipcode )
    });

    return(
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

or

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class Test extends Component {
  render(){
    if(this.props.users && this.props.users.map((d, i) => {
      console.log("values", d.name, d.email, d.address.zipcode )
    });

    return(
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: That was it, just a simple map :) Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 0):

I read from your comment, that you are using Redux.

The result of an API-fetch should be an action. In the associated reducer, you need to retrieve the payload of the action triggered by the successful request.

As others have pointed out before, it would be easier to answer and not just fire shots in the dark if you provided a code-example

Comment: I do have an action as the API-fetch result , after which I retrieve the payload of the action inside the reducer, finally resulting in the data i showed above that I just need to extract one element from. I would love to provide the code, however the project is a bit too big to upload it and just bits of it would do more harm than good:)

Comment: Is it possible, that you are forgetting the name of your reducer in acccessing the props? i.e. : "user"(…?)

Comment: You previously wrote, that `this.props.users.zipcode` yields undefined, however based on some elses request to supply the ouput of console log, the object seems to be called "this.props.user"

Comment: see the answer above, that was the problem, nothing to do with reducers or sagas :D thanks anyway!

Comment: logging `this.props.users` shows the data written above, in the description of the post, and logging `this.props.users.name` or `this.props.users.email` or anything else like that just outputs undefined

Comment: Well that's because the type of the object returned by `this.props.users` seems to be a list. That wouldn't have the attribute .name or .email. An entry out of that list however…